# NodeMCU AT Commands with UART not working

Tags: uart, nodemcu, xc8, pic16f877a

**Hi, here are my specs :-**

- PIC16F877A microcontroller
- NodeMCU (reflashed and got AT commands working via software only)
- XC8 Compiler (using MPLAB X IDE)

**Question :-**

What I'm trying to do is, trying to get the basic "AT" test functionality working (to get "OK" from the NodeMCU), and display "ESP Connected" status on my LCD.

When I used **ESPlorer-0.2.0** software, "AT" command responded with "OK" (with the NodeMCU connected via USB). But when I try to do the same thing using UART(TX, RX pins) of the PIC16F877A, I do not get "OK".

Using the given code, I always get "ESP not found".

**Circuit Diagram :-**
[image: Circuit Diagram]

**main.c :-**

```
/*
 * File:   main.c
 * Author: RJS
 *
 * Created on November 30, 2020, 3:24 PM
 */

#define _XTAL_FREQ 20000000

#define RS RD2
#define EN RD3
#define D4 RD4
#define D5 RD5
#define D6 RD6
#define D7 RD7

#include "lcd.h"
#include <xc.h>
#include <pic16f877a.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "ESP8266_functions.h"


// CONFIG
#pragma config FOSC = HS        // Oscillator Selection bits (HS oscillator)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF      // Brown-out Reset Enable bit (BOR disabled)
#pragma config LVP = OFF        // Low-Voltage (Single-Supply) In-Circuit Serial Programming Enable bit (RB3 is digital I/O, HV on MCLR must be used for programming)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data EEPROM Memory Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM code protection off)
#pragma config WRT = OFF        // Flash Program Memory Write Enable bits (Write protection off; all program memory may be written to by EECON control)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Flash Program Memory Code Protection bit (Code protection off)

void main(void) {
    TRISD = 0x00;
    
    Lcd_Start();
    Lcd_Clear();
    Initialize_ESP8266();
    /*Check if the ESP_PIC communication is successful*/

    do
    {
    Lcd_Set_Cursor(1,1);
    Lcd_Print_String("ESP not found");
    __delay_ms(100);
    }while (!esp8266_isStarted()); //wait till the ESP send back "OK"
    Lcd_Set_Cursor(1,1);
    Lcd_Print_String("ESP is connected");
    __delay_ms(1500);
    Lcd_Clear();
}
```

**ESP8266_functions.h** :-

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <xc.h>
#include <pic16f877a.h>

#define ESP8266_STATION 0x01
#define ESP8266_SOFTAP 0x02

#define ESP8266_TCP 1
#define ESP8266_UDP 0

#define ESP8266_OK 1
#define ESP8266_READY 2
#define ESP8266_FAIL 3
#define ESP8266_NOCHANGE 4
#define ESP8266_LINKED 5
#define ESP8266_UNLINK 6

int len;

void _esp8266_putch(char bt);
char _esp8266_getch();
__bit esp8266_isStarted(void); 
void esp8266_mode(unsigned char);
void _esp8266_print(unsigned const char *);
inline uint16_t _esp8266_waitFor(unsigned char *);
inline unsigned char _esp8266_waitResponse(void);

void Initialize_ESP8266(void)
{
    TRISC6 = 0; // TX Pin set as output
    TRISC7 = 1; // RX Pin set as input
    SPBRG = 10; //baudrate 115200
    TXSTAbits.BRGH  = 1;  // for high baud_rate
    TXSTAbits.SYNC  = 0;    // Asynchronous
    RCSTAbits.SPEN  = 1;    // Enable serial port pins
    TXSTAbits.TXEN  = 1;    // enable transmission
    RCSTAbits.CREN  = 1;    // enable (continuous) reception
    TXSTAbits.TX9   = 0;    // 8-bit transmission selected
    RCSTAbits.RX9   = 0;    // 8-bit reception mode selected
}

void _esp8266_putch(char bt)  
{
    while(!TXSTAbits.TRMT);  // hold the program till TX buffer is free
    TXREG = bt; //Load the transmitter buffer with the received value
}

char _esp8266_getch()
{
    if(OERR) // check for Error 
    {
        RCSTAbits.CREN = 0; //If error -> Reset 
        RCSTAbits.CREN = 1; //If error -> Reset 
    }
    
    while(!RCIF);  // hold the program till RX buffer is free
    return RCREG; //receive the value and send it to main function
}

void ESP8266_send_string(char* st_pt)
{
    while(*st_pt) //if there is a char
    _esp8266_putch(*st_pt++); //process it as a byte data
}

__bit esp8266_isStarted(void) {
    _esp8266_print("AT\r\n");
    return (_esp8266_waitResponse() == ESP8266_OK);
}

void _esp8266_print(unsigned const char *ptr) {
    while (*ptr != 0) {
        _esp8266_putch(*ptr++);
    }
}

inline uint16_t _esp8266_waitFor(unsigned char *string) {
    unsigned char so_far = 0;
    unsigned char received;
    uint16_t counter = 0;
    do {
        received = _esp8266_getch();
        counter++;
        if (received == string[so_far]) {
            so_far++;
        } else {
            so_far = 0;
        }
    } while (string[so_far] != 0);
    return counter;
}

inline unsigned char _esp8266_waitResponse(void) {
    unsigned char so_far[6] = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
    unsigned const char lengths[6] = {2,5,4,9,6,6};
    unsigned const char* strings[6] = {"OK", "ready", "FAIL", "no change", "Linked", "Unlink"};
    unsigned const char responses[6] = {ESP8266_OK, ESP8266_READY, ESP8266_FAIL, ESP8266_NOCHANGE, ESP8266_LINKED, ESP8266_UNLINK};
    unsigned char received;
    unsigned char response;
    bool continue_loop = true;
    while (continue_loop) {
        received = _esp8266_getch();
        for (unsigned char i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            if (strings[i][so_far[i]] == received) {
                so_far[i]++;
                if (so_far[i] == lengths[i]) {
                    response = responses[i];
                    continue_loop = false;
                }
            } else {
                so_far[i] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return response;
}
```

I got the code from [here](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/interfacing-pic-microcontroller-with-esp8266), and removed some redundant functions for asking this question. In the original code, there was a data type `bit`, which I replace to `__bit` after searching the internet.

> **UPDATE**

After connecting the NodeMCU ground to PIC16F877A ground, and changing of some faulty wires, I could get the "Sending" part of the AT commands working. (I tested with configuring a soft access point)

But still, there's no reply from the NodeMCU. (still displaying ESP not found) But to my surprise, when I reset the PIC, I see "ESP Connected" for a very short amount of time.

Can anybody please give me some advice?

Comment: Try to monitor the UART signals between the PIC and ESP8266 with a scope or cheapie USB-based logic analyzer, or as a least preferred option, the receive side of a USB-UART connected to your PC running something to print (or hexdump?) anything received.

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't the fact that half of the PIC power supply pins are not connected?

Comment: @Justme connected those two but didn't work either. BTW, I'm still learning this stuff.

Comment: I think you used voltage divider on rx pin of the ESP for logic conversion. If it is, to make the logic convertion reliable, I use [BSS138 N-FET](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/BSS138-D.PDF)